# How do I get the id of parent div, then take out the first 3 letters of the name and store the last digit of the name into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="tip1">
    <div class="tip-icon"></div>
</div>
<div id="tip2">
    <div class="tip-icon"></div>
</div>
<div id="tip3">
    <div class="tip-icon"></div>
</div>
<div class="1 content"></div>
<div class="2 content"></div>
<div class="3 content"></div>
```

And I have a jQuery function like this:

```
$('.tip-icon').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.1').addClass('tip-show'); //Change .1 to a variable
});
$('.tip-icon').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.1').removeClass('tip-show2'); //Change .1 to a variable
});
```

But instead of having $('.1'), I want it to be the class numbers 1-3 depending on which "tip-icon" was hovered. I need to make is so that on "tip-icon" mouseenter it will take the parent div's id and delete the first 3 letters so that it is just the number left and store it into a variable. I then want to take this variable and use it in $('???').addClass('tip-show'); so that the ??? are replaced by the variable to make it so that one of divs with the classes 1-3 will get the 'tip-show' class added depending on which 'tip-icon' was hovered.

https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted? The OP has described his goal, the problem and provided an example. What more do people want?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The alt-text on the downvote reads: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)".  I personally feel this shows no research effort, as each of the three points in the title are trivial on their own.  I also feel that this question would not be useful as a reference for anyone in the future as it is not phrased in such a way to be searchable, and again is so trivial that anyone with basic, functional knowledge wouldn't ask it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont do all that string mashing just to get the id out of the class. Instead tie your elements/functionality together using `data-*` attributes

```
<div id="tip1" data-tipid="1">
    <div class="tip-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can use that within your code to get the right id (actually, in your case class name)

```
$('.tip-icon').mouseenter(function () {
    var tipId = $(this).parent().data('tipid');
    $('.' + tipId).addClass('tip-show'); //Change .1 to a variable
});
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/6/

Comment: So many ways, but I think using the data attribute is the proper way of doing things, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hack around the string of the `class` attribute as you can simply use `index()` to retrieve a numerical value representing the position of an element within a selector. Try this:

```
$('.tip-icon').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.' + ($(this).index('.tip-icon') + 1)).addClass('tip-show'); 
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.' + ($(this).index('.tip-icon') + 1)).removeClass('tip-show'); 
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/2/)

This can then be made shorter by using `hover` and `toggleClass`:

```
$('.tip-icon').hover(function () {
    $('.' + ($(this).index('.tip-icon') + 1)).toggleClass('tip-show'); 
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Like this you mean?

```
$('.tip-icon').mouseenter(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').substring(3, 1);
  $('#'+id).addClass('tip-show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make use of html5 `data` attribute:
Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/8/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `hover` for this as combination of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Use `regex` to get the number in the `id` of parent.

```
$('.tip-icon').hover(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace(/[a-z]/ig, '');
    // Get the number from the id

    $('.' + id).addClass('tip-show').show();
}, function () {
    $('.content').removeClass('tip-show').hide();
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/oak4L9ga/9/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".tip-icon").hover(

function () {
    $('.' + $(this).parent().attr("id").replace('tip', '')).addClass('tip-show');
}, function () {
    $('.' + $(this).parent().attr("id").replace("tip", "")).removeClass('tip-show');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/10/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery chaining concept.

Check JQuery:

```
$('.tip-icon').mouseenter(function () {
    var idValue = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').substr(3, 4);
    $('.'+idValue).addClass('tip-show');
});
$('.tip-icon').mouseleave(function () {
    var id_Value = $(this).parent('div').attr('id').substr(3, 4);
    $('.'+id_Value).removeClass('tip-show');
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/oak4L9ga/11/